# ORA-02293 - Check constraint violated when enable constraint

Tags: oracle, constraints

I have a migration script in between 2 different schema database. 
The script does 3 things:
 1. Disable constraint
 2. Insert record from old schema to new schema
 3. Enable constraint

During enable constraint, it encouter `ORA-02293 - Check constraint violated:` at the following 2 tables:

`ALTER TABLE TRANSACTION_TYPE ENABLE CONSTRAINT TRANS_TYPE_NN2;
 ALTER TABLE TRANSACTIONS ENABLE CONSTRAINT TRANSACTION_NN16;`

I found that these 2 constraints are not exist in the old schema. Anything went wrong in the table structure definition of these 2 tables?

Comment: Some of the data the script inserted is violating the Check constraint, either `TRANS_TYPE_NN2` or `TRANSACTION_NN16` . You should see the definition of these constraints to know the column/condition and then see which rows in the table are violating it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check data for table `TRANSACTION_TYPE` to see if there are duplicate data or alter constraint `TRANS_TYPE_NN2` if needed.

Same for table `TRANSACTIONS`.

Comment: There has no duplicated data in table `TRANSACTION_TYPE`. However these 2 constraints were originally disabled in the new schema, will it be possible cause error when the script try to enable them?

Comment: It depends on the data. Either the data or the constraint needs to be modified. You can share the data and the definition of the constraint if needed.

Comment: i share the table script in new schema:
 CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION_TYPE 
   ( "TXN_TYPE_CODE" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) CONSTRAINT "TRANS_TYPE_NN1" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"VERSION_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 CONSTRAINT "TRANS_TYPE_NN2" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP CONSTRAINT "TRANS_TYPE_NN3" NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"TXN_TYPE_DESC" VARCHAR2(80 CHAR), 
"TXN_TYPE_NAME" VARCHAR2(40 CHAR), 
"SCOPE" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
"INSTRUMENT" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
"REGION" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR), 
CONSTRAINT "TRANS_TYPE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TXN_TYPE_CODE")

Comment: You can check the data by this sql:
`SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_TYPE WHERE VERSION_ID IS NULL;`
You need to delete the data or update `VERSION_ID` to some value `NOT NULL`.